# AES-128 for File Encryption on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm currently working on an application for encrypting a file using the AES algorithm. I'm aware that Android provides a convenient way to do this kind of job by using `EncryptedFile`. I only need AES-128, but the `EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme` only offers the AES-256 option, as shown in the code example from [Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography#write-file) below.

```
// Although you can define your own key generation parameter specification, it's
// recommended that you use the value specified here.
val keyGenParameterSpec = MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC
val mainKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(keyGenParameterSpec)

// Create a file with this name or replace an entire existing file
// that has the same name. Note that you cannot append to an existing file,
// and the filename cannot contain path separators.
val fileToWrite = "my_sensitive_data.txt"
val encryptedFile = EncryptedFile.Builder(
    File(DIRECTORY, fileToWrite),
    applicationContext,
    mainKeyAlias,
    EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB
).build()

val fileContent = "MY SUPER-SECRET INFORMATION"
        .toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
encryptedFile.openFileOutput().apply {
    write(fileContent)
    flush()
    close()
}
```

Is there any other class or perhaps a workaround that I can use to accomplish this task?

My first thought is that I can create my own AES class for encryption and decryption, but since Android already provides this option with their `EncryptedFile`, wouldn't it be nice to use that class instead?

Anyway, this is my current workaround, a code that I found on a [gist](https://gist.github.com/flymrc/31f0efe6cf927ff8d8e79d4c9ca9eb5c) to encrypt and decrypt using the AES algorithm.

```
// ref: https://www.baeldung.com/java-aes-encryption-decryption

import java.util.*
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec


fun decrypt(algorithm: String, cipherText: String, key: SecretKeySpec, iv: IvParameterSpec): String {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm)
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv)
    val plainText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText))
    return String(plainText)
}

fun encrypt(algorithm: String, inputText: String, key: SecretKeySpec, iv: IvParameterSpec): String {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm)
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv)
    val cipherText = cipher.doFinal(inputText.toByteArray())
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText)
}

val inputText = "abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
val algorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"
val key = SecretKeySpec("1234567890123456".toByteArray(), "AES")
val iv = IvParameterSpec(ByteArray(16))

val cipherText = encrypt(algorithm, inputText, key, iv)
val plainText = decrypt(algorithm, cipherText, key, iv)

assert(inputText == plainText)
```

Comment: What do you have against AES-256? You've been given an easy button, go ahead and press it.

Comment: is there any performance difference by any chance? I really don't know what the performance difference is between those two.

Comment: Generally, AES-256 is slightly slower than AES-128, though it may not be noticeable at all if I/O dominates throughput. The only concern is if you're using it so much that energy use/battery drain is a major issue. Even then, I would do a benchmark first before I assume anything.

Comment: Since AES-128 10 rounds and AES-256 14, we expect %40 performance decrease, though this is not a problem in modern CPUs.

Comment: So it appears that I should use the one provided by Android. Nonetheless, since this is just a learning project, I intend to modify the EncryptedFile class for the sake of my learning progress. Thanks, everyone!